# Is my name a rigid designator if I had an identical twin in a possible world?

Tags: possible-worlds, rigid-designator

In examples I have read defining the term "rigid designator," proper names are used as an example, e.g. Aristotle vs the author of the Nicomachean Ethics. I could well be overanalyzing what is meant as just a suggestive, simplified example, but I don't see how proper names attached to people could be rigid when people may not be.

It doesn't seem a stretch to say that there are possible worlds with more people than ours. To be concrete, one of two twins often dies in the womb; in worlds where some particular such pair of twins both live, very likely one of the pair would be given the name of the surviving twin in our world, and in some possible world the twin that died in our world would get the name of the twin that lived in our world.

Now, the above really is only an example that the designated object need not not have a the same rigid designator across all possible worlds, which is certainly a trivial point (there are possible worlds where parents name children differently or speak different languages). But biologically, it's equally possible that children in our world who never had a sibling in utero would, in a a possible world, have a twin, as it appears to be a matter of chance whether an embryo divided in that manner. In that case, which of the two twins in that world would be designated by our rigid designator for the single child in our world?

The whole twin thing isn't important in its details, but is just the first concrete example I came up with. More broadly, given that there is not, in general, a canonical injection mapping people in our world to those in an arbitrary possible world, how could a proper name be said to refer to the "same" person in all possible worlds?

Apologies if my extremely limited understanding (entirely from popular accounts) of philosophy means that everything above is nonsense.

Comment: "How could a proper name be said to refer to the "same" person in all possible worlds?" By definition. This is how Kripkean possible worlds are constructed, around fixed individuals. One does not pick some "platonically given" possible world and then go look for "corresponding" individuals in it, potentially getting "confused" by an identical twin. This is how it might work for worlds based on definite descriptions or Lewis's counterparts, where "transworld identity" questions come up. Kripke's possible worlds are simply built on individuals from the actual world with rigid identity.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Obviously, some common proper names like "Thomas Smith" cannot by themselves uniquely identify one person within the set of all humans, even within just one world. Proper names can intentionally be used in a non-rigid way, but would typically explicitly be marked like "a person named Thomas Smith" if a speaker intended non-rigid usage. When using proper names in logic as rigid identifier, then only such possible worlds are included in the argument in which the designator uniquely identifies an object.

Comment: @Conifold and tkruse, thanks for the clarifications. I had guessed that I might have been abusing what "possible" meant and that "possible worlds" had a stricter definition. Since by definition "only such possible worlds are included in the argument in which the designator uniquely identifies an object," is the statement that "proper names [intended rigidly] are rigid designators" really just a tautology, since "rigid designators" are defined to make that true (and non-rigid uses of proper names have to be excluded)?

Comment: Kripke argues informally, based on linguistic intuitions, that prevailing modal reasoning in common talk uses proper names (and natural kinds) rigidly, and then constructs a technical model of possible worlds that bakes it in by design. So yes, in his possible worlds rigid designation is "tautological".